# Could not find "Estimated Work" field in Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-boards

I am sending a POST request to create a task in the Azure DevOps via REST API,

but I could not find the field "Estimated Work" and I really need to populate it.

Any help with this?

Checking the documentation I could only find those 3 related to estimates:

[image]

But my version has this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The field **Estimated Work** is the **Original Estimate** field, the 'Estimated Work' it's just a label, but behind the scenes, the field is: `Microsoft.VSVS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate`.

You can hove with the mouse on the **Estimated Work** label and see in the pop-up the real field name.

Comment: I've updated the screenshot, the mouse hover shows only the field name as "Estimated Work"

I've tried to set as string and as double/int, but the field does not get updated

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I found out that this is a Custom field in my project, so I have to use it as:
                    path = "/fields/Custom.EstimatedWork",

Comment: This is Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate and not Microsoft.VSVS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate (VSVS->VSTS).

Answer (score 2):

Agree with **Shayki** and just to add some details with related doc and how to call the rest api:

`Original Estimate` represents the amount of `estimated work` required to complete a task. Typically, this field doesn't change after it is assigned. You can check [Fill out the task form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/add-tasks?view=azure-devops#fill-out-the-task-form)
.

1.HTTP: `POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=5.1`

2.Request Body(application/json-patch+json):

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "MyTask"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate",
    "from": null,
    "value": "15"
  }
]
```

Then one task with name `MyTask` will be created, and its Estimated Work should be `15`. (Only the value element above need to be changed when creating new work items)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys, I found out that this specific field is a Custom field in my project, as you can see in the Updated screenshot of the mouse hover Field Name, I was trying to set it but it was not updating using "OriginalEstimate",

so I've changed it to:

```
new
{
      op = "add",
      path = "/fields/Custom.EstimatedWork",
      value = 4
},
```